# How do i make a child game object affect the parent?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a game like Super Mario. The player is a circle and the enemy is a square that goes left and right after hitting a wall. If the enemy touches the player on the sides the player dies so to survive the player has to jump on the head of the enemy to kill it.

I separated the enemy to two parts body and head (body is parent and the head is a child). Now killing the player is already done but I'm stuck at killing the enemy. **How do I kill (destroy) the parent when the player touches the head (child)?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to add a collider to the child/head, [BoxCollider2D for example](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/BoxCollider2D.html).  Then you can handle the Collision event and call a method on the parent object.

It would look something like:

```
// In the child/head
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
{
    var goomba = transform.Parent.GetComponent<Goomba>();
    goomba.Kill();
}
```

This is probably the simplest way, but I think there is a way to propagate collisions to the parent, can't remember though.

Edit:

Apparently,

> If you're using a Rigidbody with the character, you can get this out of the box. :)

Found that in this answer: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/151670/unity-how-to-detect-collision-occuring-on-child-object-from-a-parent-script

Comment: thats what i was trying to do 
i added this script to the child

`public GameObject parent;
    
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("player"))
        {
            Destroy(parent);
        }
    }`

Comment: @kuruttakao You're using the TRIGGER method, which is meant to be used when one of the colliders is set to be a trigger. Triggers don't actually collide with objects, but there collision boxes will tell you when things overlap.